# I need to initialize a 2D array by reading lines from a .txt file then splitting each individual line every time a semicolon shows up in each line

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, split

Here is my problem:

I have a program (using the console) that prompts users for data as such:

Name:

Date:

Birthday:

The user enters the data, then the data is recorded in a .txt file, each line being one instance the user entered data, with each individual piece of data being separated by a semicolon. The text file looks like this:

```
John Smith;7/14/2015;6/5/1980

Jane Doe;7/15/2015;3/4/1975
```

What I want to do is take each line of text, split it by semicolon, and put all of that text in one 2D array. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void lineSplitCreator()
{
    string[, ] portionsOfAllData; //the 2D array
    string[] linesOfPatientData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Administrator.Rahul-HP\Desktop\test\dataOfPatient.txt");
    //read all lines and put them into this array
    foreach (string s in linesOfPatientData) //attempt at initializing the 2D array
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            portionsOfAllData[i, ] = s.Split(';');
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm not sure how many elements the `Split()` could produce, I suggest using a jagged array.

A jagged array is declared like:

```
string[][] myJaggedArray;
```

For your code, make the following changes and you should be good to go.

```
public static void lineSplitCreator()
{
    string[] linesOfPatientData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Administrator.Rahul-HP\Desktop\test\dataOfPatient.txt");
    // This is your jagged array.  We know how many rows will have from linesOfPatientData
    string[][] portionsOfAllData = new string[linesOfPatientData.Length][]; // The 2D array

    // Read all lines and put them into this array
    for (int i = 0; i < linesOfPatientData.Length; i++)
    {
        portionsOfAllData[i] = linesOfPatientData[i].Split(';');
    }
}
```

Or use a `List<string[]>`

```
public static void lineSplitCreator()
{
    string[] linesOfPatientData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Administrator.Rahul-HP\Desktop\test\dataOfPatient.txt");
    List<string[]> portionsOfAllData = new List<string[]>();

    // Read all lines and put them into this array
    foreach (string s in linesOfPatientData)
    {
        portionsOfAllData.Add(s.Split(';'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want a 2D array, you need to know exactly how many elements are in a line... as mentioned in another answer, a jagged array might be a better fit, but, this is how you can do it with a 2D array:

```
var testString = @"John Smith;7/14/2015;6/5/1980
Jane Doe;7/15/2015;3/4/1975";

var arr = testString.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var output = new string[arr.Length, 3];
for(var rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < arr.Length; rowNumber++)
{
    var line = arr[rowNumber];
    var lineItems = line.Split(';');
    for(var columnNumber=0; columnNumber < 3; columnNumber++)
    {
        output[rowNumber,columnNumber] = lineItems[columnNumber];
    }

}
```